# Approving the filtered values of list using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have a `list`, a `list filter` and two `date filters`(Start date and end date) in a page. First I have to filter list using this filters and then I have to approve whatever item are left in the list after filtering.

I am using the following JavaScript code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

//var siteUrl = '/projects/SharePoint2013-Demo/TimesheetManagementSystem/';
var oList = null;
var web = null;
var clientContext  = null;



function retrieveListItems() {

var filterValue =document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl41_g_1c91c2d4_fbbb_4792_8507_ba589e5be222_SpListPicker_SelectionBox");
var StartDate=document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl41_g_ed4beb82_8f7e_4389_bb35_a44188462aab_DateFilterPicker_DateFilterPickerDate");  
var EndDate=document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl41_g_07c2185d_e903_4010_8a84_b2d9536a5549_DateFilterPicker_DateFilterPickerDate");
alert(filterValue.value );
alert(StartDate.value);
alert(EndDate.value);


    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TimeSheetList');
    clientContext.load(oList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(LoadList, onQueryFailed);        


}


function LoadWeb123(sender,args)
{
    //oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('TimeSheetList');

    //clientContext.load(this.oList);
    //clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.LoadList), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));   

}



function LoadList()
{
           var  camlQuery= new SP.CamlQuery();
                   camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'/><Value Type='User'>vikash kumar</Value></Eq><Geq><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='DateTime'>2015-07-10T12:00:00Z</Value></Geq></And><Leq><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='DateTime'>2015-07-17T12:00:00Z</Value></Leq></And></Where></Query></View>");  

   camlQuery.set_viewXml(camlQuery);

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);


    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));   

}


 function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';


    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                var ID= oListItem.get_id();
                alert(ID);
                }
}


function onQueryFailed() {
//    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    alert('error');
}


</script>

<button type="button" onclick="retrieveListItems()">Approve!</button>
```

But this is not working, it gives error alert.

What could be done?
Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Where do you get the access denied error? Have you checked if you have at least read permissions to the list since you are only retrieving values?

Comment: there is one ows.js file,in this file it is showing permission denied error when I am debugging the code in internet explorer. It is showing the first three alerts that I have given bt after that it is showing this permission denied error in ows.js file.

Comment: Which particular line in the above code fails? While getting the items, while getting the list? Where exactly?

Comment: clientContext.load(oList);  while debugging,it is not going to this code.

Comment: Check if you can access the list using: 
`http://sharepointsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TimeSheetList')` in your browser.

Comment: yes, I am able to access list

Comment: Ok so you clearly have permissions to the site. Could you try just getting the lists (part where you're getting the error) using Rest api with JavaScript and see if it works? If it does, you can continue with this approach.

Comment: I don't know rest api, can anything else be done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25978/discussion-between-uberz91-and-vikash-kumar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small change in code and it worked..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//var siteUrl = '/projects/';
var oList = null;
var web = null;
var clientContext  = null;



function retrieveListItems(sender, args) {

var filterValue =document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl41_g_1c91c2d4_fbbb_4792_8507_ba589e5be222_SpListPicker_SelectionBox");
var StartDate=document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl41_g_ed4beb82_8f7e_4389_bb35_a44188462aab_DateFilterPicker_DateFilterPickerDate");  
var EndDate=document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl41_g_07c2185d_e903_4010_8a84_b2d9536a5549_DateFilterPicker_DateFilterPickerDate");
alert(filterValue.value );
alert(StartDate.value);
alert(EndDate.value);


    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TimeSheetList');
    clientContext.load(oList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.LoadList), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        


}



function LoadList(sender, args)
{
           var  camlQuery= new SP.CamlQuery();
           var query = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='User'>Vikash Kumar</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
  camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);


    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));   

}


 function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

     alert(collListItem.get_count());

    var listItemInfo = '';


    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                var ID= oListItem.get_id();
                alert(ID);
                }
}


function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}


</script>

<button type="button" onclick="retrieveListItems()">button1!</button>
```